# How do I compute $\int_{|z|=r} x \, dz$ by use of a parameter?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

How do I compute

$$\int_{|z|=r} x \, dz$$

by use of a parameter?

Comment: Why is this downvoted?  If you don't understand my question, please tell what's wrong with it so that I can fix it.

Comment: Possibly the reason for the down-vote is that the question is phrased in language appropriate for assigning homework.  That tends to be frowned on here.  Whoever down-voted it should have explained that, but usually that doesn't happen. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: I feel like my questions always get ignored here so I try to explain them as simply as possible. Ok, this has been noted. I'll check out the question that appears to be a duplicate.

Comment: Related, but not a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

let $z=r e^{i \theta}$ so that $dz = i r e^{i \theta} d \theta $

assuming that $x=Re(z)= r \cos \theta $ ..

$$I = i r^2 \int_0^{2 \pi} \cos \theta \; e^{i \theta} d \theta$$

I wouldn't be at all surprised if the answer turned out to be zero.

Comment: Surprise! (You can tell the integral is not zero because the real part of the integral is $\int_0^{2\pi} \cos^2 \theta \ d\theta.$)